# using multiple es6 map and make it async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const eventBarData = data.map(obj => prepareEventBar(obj.calendar))

const mapToSpaceData = eventBarData.map(obj => ({
  space_name: obj.space.display.name,
  ...obj
}))
```

Above code won't work because both run concurrently? how to ensure eventBarData done processing then run another map? must I wrap map within a map? I don't want to use callback in prepareEventBar function.

Comment: map is already synchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `prepareEventBar` return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Then you can just use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const eventBarDataPromises = data.map(obj => prepareEventBar(obj.calendar))

Promise.all(eventBarDataPromises)
  .then(eventBarData => eventBarData.map(obj => ...))
  .then(mapToSpaceData => ...
```

Alternatively, if your environment supports it or you're using a transpiler, an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) might be somewhat cleaner:

```
// this code must be wrapped in an async function
const eventBarData = await Promise.all(
  data.map(obj => prepareEventBar(obj.calendar))
);

const mapToSpaceData = eventBarData.map(obj => ...);
```

Comment: how to return a promise?

Comment: It would probably be best to read the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)